# Flutter & Dart, How to Pass Barcode Scan value into TextFormField on Scan and Update Text

Tags: forms, dart, flutter, state

How can I pass the barcode value into the TextForField after it scans? The Barcode function passes the barcode value to the String barcode. It's the ListTile Object with the OnTap function defined as scan();

I want to pass that value back into the field immediately. I tried a setState() function but couldn't quite figure it out. Thanks.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'ItemData.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';
import 'Barcode.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class CreateWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CreateState createState() => CreateState();

}
Data newData = new Data();

class CreateState extends State<CreateWidget> {
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
void submit() {
    _formKey.currentState.save();

}



  String barcode = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        flex: 0,
        child: Center(
          child: Form(
            key: this._formKey,
            child: Flex(
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: TextFormField (
                    initialValue: '',
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      icon: new Icon(Icons.info),
                      hintText: "Title",
                    ),
                    validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? null : 'Not a valid Title',
                    onSaved: (val) => newData.title = val,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: TextFormField(
                initialValue: '',
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.info),
                  hintText: "Location",
                ),
                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Location is required' : null,
                onSaved: (val) => newData.location = val,
              ),
            ),
```

/////////////////////////////////////
This is the list tile where I want the action to happen.

```
            ListTile(
              title: TextFormField(
                initialValue: '',
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.info),
                  hintText: "Barcode",
                ),
                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Barcode is required' : null,
                onSaved: (val) => newData.barcode = val,
              ),
              trailing: new Icon(Icons.search),
              onTap: () {
                {scan();}
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: TextFormField(
                initialValue: '',
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.info),
                  hintText: "Type",
                ),
                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Type is required' : null,
                onSaved: (val) => newData.type = val,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.access_time),
              title: Text(_getDateNow()),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              child: new Text('Create'),
              onPressed: () {
                submit();
                createItem();
                Navigator.pop(context, true);

                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
  }

 Future scan() async {
try {
  String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
  setState(() => this.barcode = barcode);
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
    setState(() {
      this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
    });
  } else {
    setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
  }
} on FormatException{
  setState(() => this.barcode = 'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)');
} catch (e) {
  setState(() => this.barcode = 'Unknown error: $e');
    }
  }


}

Future createItem() async {
  Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
  CollectionReference reference = 
  Firestore.instance.collection('items');
  await reference.add({"title": newData.title, "location": newData.location, "type": newData.type,"date": _getDateNow(), "editing": false, "barcode": newData.barcode,});

  });
}

_getDateNow() {
  var now = new DateTime.now();
  var formatter = new DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy H:mm');
  return formatter.format(now);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Text From Field Make a controller where you initialised the String barcode as follows :-

```
TextEditingContoller c = new TextEditingController();
```

and in the list tile inside text form field set its controller as c and inside ontap function of list tile do this .

```
scan().then(()=>setState((){
    c.text = barcode;
}));
```

then function takes a parameter which is automatically suggested to you as you write the code . I have tried only in VSCode and android studio .
So make sure you pass the right parameter to then function or you might get an error .

Comment: Not working. First it threw an error that it was looking for initial value to be null. Once I set the initial value to null and passed c into the then() method, it scanned and tried to set text to the barcode value read, but failed to set null to a text value.

Comment: onTap: () {
                    
                   scan().then(
                     (c)
                     {
                     setState((){
                    c.text = barcode;
                  });
                   });
                   
                  },

Comment: Here's the first part of the error [VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'text=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: text="9780976423317"
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:46:5)
#1      CreateState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/NewUser/Projects/FlutterTest/beacon_app/lib/entry.dart:85:23)

Answer (score 0):

So, looks like the then() needs a type declared. Passing in String fixed it.

```
scan().then((String)=>setState((){
    c.text = barcode;
}));
```

Comment: My bad . when u write the code in any ide. and u write then() function it automatically shows you the parameters to be passed yo then function . and as i replied drom my mobile i wasnt able to see what parameters were supposed to be passed into the then() function. i hoped you'll see to that yourself .
i'll edit my ans by the way . thnks for pointing .